# Installing TChart2014 & XE7

Tags: delphi, installation, teechart, delphi-xe7

I have been using TChart (Pro) for years and currently on TChart2014. I have recently upgraded Delphi to XE7 but the installer does not recognize XE7. I downloaded the latest Bin and source code files from the download center but XE7 is not there (Actually, since I removed XE2, it says there are no IDE's installed). Is there another installation set lurking somewhere that is not 'public'

Comment: Check your version http://www.steema.com/entry/224/TeeChart_2014.12.140923_VCL_2FFMX_release and/or contact the vendor

Comment: @SirRufo Actually there is newer version already available. http://www.steema.com/entry/239/TeeChart_2015.14.150120_VCL_2FFMX_release Also since Delphi XE8 is already out it is just matter of time when new version comes out.

Comment: @SilverWarior I know it is but do we know if the OP has a valid license for that new version? Buy the newer version is not a solution if you have already bought a version that should work

Comment: If you hold a TeeChart Pro subscription, it may have expired before support for XE7 came out. Please contact our Sales Dept. at sales at steema dot com with your customer and license details. They will provide more information on your case. Thanks.

Comment: I think you may be right. Having checked the dates, it seems I missed the cut off for XE7 inclusion by 3 weeks. Not a happy bunny.

Comment: As I have the source files, I should be able to recompile manually and make it work (It may not be perfect but it should work at least). Are there any instructions for manual compiles ( I don't actually use all the FMX stuff, just the basic chart for win32 and win64)

Comment: The release notes on the web site states:-TeeChart v2012/2013 VCL/FMX customers may download the version at no-charge from the customer download page. There does not seem to a 'time of purchase' restriction indicated. I'll contact them directly. Thanks

Comment: @PhilipO the message at the news item involves a valid license subscription (http://www.steema.com/licensing/subscription). Since version name doesn't follow natural year strictly, there might still be TeeChart 2012 clients with a valid subscription at that time. Anyway, that being on September, looks like an error from our (Steema Software) side. Anyway, please contact our Sales Dept. They might be able to solve that.

Comment: Updating TeeChart source is usually easy. I'm still using 5 year old version in XE7.

Comment: I've been on to sales and they simply said "you too late, not valid, buy the upgrade for $300" in a nut shell. Not happy at all since I have been with Steema since the days of Delphi 1. I just want it to compile in XE7 without any problems. I don't want to "upgrade" just to make it work. Time to move on I think.

Comment: @PhilipO I checked that with the Sales Dept. They told me it was 3 months, not 3 weeks, since it had expired. Anyway, they extended your subscription until the day of the XE7 release. You should be able to download it now. Please bear in mind that adding support for new environments and extending products functionality is part of Steema Software's business.

Comment: Actually, my subscription ended in 1st July (Not end of July as I thought). Anyway I am very happy with the response I received and this has saved me a lot of work trying to get the version for XE6 to compile and work. Thanks to all involved.

Answer (score 0):

Following up the comments to the question, the answer is that the subscription license needs to be renewed/extended to get access to the [TeeChart 2014.12.140923 VCL/FMX release](http://www.steema.com/entry/224/TeeChart_2014.12.140923_VCL_2FFMX_release), which is the first version adding RAD Studio XE7 support, or a newer version.